# Unmasking adds an extra whitespace for BPE tokenizer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, tokenize, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

I created a custom BPE tokenizer for pre-training a Roberta model, utilizing the following parameters (I tried to align it with the default parameters of BPE for RoBERTa.):

```
from tokenizers.models import BPE
from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer
from tokenizers.processors import RobertaProcessing

tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()
tokenizer.normalizer = normalizers.BertNormalizer(lowercase = False)
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(Data_full, vocab_size = 50264, min_frequency = 2, special_tokens = ["<s>", "<pad>", "</s>", "<unk>"])
tokenizer.add_special_tokens(["<mask>"])
tokenizer.post_processor = RobertaProcessing(sep = ("</s>", 2), cls = ("<s>", 0), trim_offsets = False, add_prefix_space = False)
tokenizer.enable_padding(direction = 'right', pad_id = 1, pad_type_id = 1, pad_token = "<pad>", length = 512)
```

When pre-training a Roberta model with this tokenizer, I observe unusual behavior during the unmasking process:

```
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast
tokenizer_in = Tokenizer.from_file('tokenizer_file')
tokenizer_m = RobertaTokenizerFast(tokenizer_object=tokenizer_in, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True) 
unmasker = pipeline('fill-mask', model=model_m, tokenizer = tokenizer_m)

unmasker("Capital of France is <mask>.")
```

The output consistently appears as follows: `Capital of France is  Paris`. I'm curious about the persistent extra space before 'Paris'. I believe activating the `clean_up_tokenization_spaces` option might resolve this. Could there be an error in my code leading to this issue? This happens for all unmasking tasks. Also, when I conduct a test with a command like `unmasker("Capital of France is<mask>.")`, the quality improves and the issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For disambiguation especially of beginning of word vs. word-piece Tokenizers can use a leading space. `"Paris"` and `" Paris"` are two different (collection of )tokens and also two different embeddings.

Ideally the model could differentiate between the two cases:

- `("is") -> " Paris"`
- `("is", " ") -> "Paris"`

However, as you see this is not the case here.
(Very) Roughly speaking as leading-spaces occur more often in sentence structures `... in Paris` vs. `"Paris is ..."` the model will be more certain in the `" Paris"` token than in the `Paris` one. I assume a model with more parameters (or more specific pretraining) could better disambiguate between the two cases.

TL;DR: Unmasking does not create an arbitrary leading space. `" Paris"` is then token to go when its not at the start of the sentence and the mask should include the leading space as well.

---

Note: `clean_up_tokenization_spaces` is especially related to *punctuation*, e.g. `" ?" -> "?", " ,"->","`. I assume it is True for the common tokenizers as False would create more unnatural looking sentences.
It does not clean up leading-spaces of normal words.

Comment: Even when I keep up with the training process, it seems we still have this problem whenever I add <mask> at the end of a sentence.